# Where to put config file for my own library and have the path injected into Symfony service

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

Ok, so I have a library that I've written that I'd like to use in Symfony. It has it's configuration stored in a yml file.

At the moment I have the yml file in `src/AppBundle/Resources/config`. I need the path of this config file to be injected into the service. At the moment I have simply hard coded a relative path to the config file in the `services.yml`:-

`service_name:
   class: My\Library\Service
   arguments: ["../src/AppBundle/Resources/config/my_library_config.yml"]`

I feel like this isn't the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. The library consumer should tell `My\Library\Service` where the configuration lays, though of course `My\Library\Service` may make reasonable default assumptions. That leaves the application for the decision point, which may absolutely use relative references.

Comment: "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Resources/config/my_library_config.yml" should also do the trick.  Look in some of the other app/config files and you will see this used quite frequently to create absolute paths.  You can also define a app_bundle_dir parameter inside of your dependency injection extension.  That will remove the link between app and your bundle.

Comment: you could wirte a simple standalone bundle which only works as a bridge from Symfony to your library. Then you can use the normal configuration handling of symfony to inject all you need to the service. see https://github.com/cwd/easyname-bridge-bundle for a very simple bridge to a third party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Extension` class to generate the path for you and replace the argument when the container compiles.

However, Symfony already has a [configuration processing method](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html). The extension option is kind of useless without the configuration though, so if you're not building it to be re-used, use `%kernel.root_dir%` to prepend the right path.

If you *are* going to be reusing it, there's no point in making the configuration static. In that case I recommend you to make a configuration option so that people can configure your bundle/options theirself.

Is there an actual reason you want to make your own config though? You could simply define a parameter and store the whole config in a parameter, that saves you from creating and parsing your own configuration file and allows you to benefit from the parameter system.

Comment: No there isn't any reason apart from that's the way I originally built the library before I was going to be using it in Symfony. So if I have a parameter with several entries under it and inject the parameter, would I get it as an associative array?

Comment: yaml is simply converted to an array of data, nested arrays are supported